# How to calculate 95%CI for F1 score and Matthews correlation coefficient?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

How can I calculate the 95%CI for F1 score, Matthews correlation coefficient and fraction correct ((TN+TP)/(TP+TN+FP+FN)) when I evaluating a perfomance of binominal diagnostic test?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

F1, MCC and other such metrics can be thought of as proportions, since they are in [0,1]. The binomial proportion confidence interval can be estimated with (using normal approximation)

[image]

Comment: MCC is on the [-1,1] interval.

Comment: @fccoelho This can be easily solved by normalizing the score to [0,1].

Comment: I believe this is actually wrong, especially for the F1-score. When you compare what you get vs. what you get when bootstrapping, you see that this CI is by far too narrow in imbalanced class problems. You seem to get closer to the bootstrap CI, if you use the formula with TP+FP+FN as the denominator.

Comment: @Björn Yes, the binomial confidence interval estimated using a normal approximation is unreliable when the sample size is small or the success probability is close to 0 or 1, this is a known fact. In that case an exact CI would be more appropriate (for ex. Clopper-Pearson).

Comment: @user2974951 It's not just the normal approximation, even for a exact binomial your denominator would be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

A default answer for getting a CI for a quantity you do not have a simple CI-formula for is to bootstrap. You repeatedly draw the total number of records with replacement from your data and then you calculate the metric of interest on each of these bootstrapped datasets. With this list of calculated metrics you calculate a bootstrap confidence interval.

For fraction correction, sensitivity and specificity, any method for getting a binomial CI will also do just fine. For the F1 score this is not as simple. You come close to the bootstrap CI, if you use the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles of a beta distribution with parameters F1 score*(TP+FP+FN) and (1-F1 score)*(TP+FP+FN) (or perhaps adding 1/3 or 1/2 to each of these). That is motivated by taking a Bayesian approach with very vague priors.