# Can you compute errors bars from Precision and Recall?

Tags: metric, confusion-matrix, object-detection

I am performing an object detection task for counting cars in an image. I have the confusion matrix (TP, FP, FP, TN) of the model. I guess TN is just zero in this case, as we aren't detecting where a car is not.

How do I use these numbers to say something like the number of cars should be within X% of the true number?

For example in a photograph where there are really 90 cars. The models predicts 84 things that it thinks are cars and 73 of them are actually cars and 11 are not cars. So precision is 73/84 and recall is 73/90 - what do I need to compute to say the count will be within X%?

Comment: This is not really done, however you could treat this as a binomial distribution, where you are only interested in count for TN (1), everything else is (0), in that case you can estimate a binomial proportion confidence interval for your TN.

Comment: Hmmm that's interesting @user2974951 do you know how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370791/how-to-calculate-95ci-for-f1-score-and-matthews-correlation-coefficient/370904?noredirect=1#comment754377_370904